# NSEvent feeding to system

Tags: objective-c, nsevent

Can someone show an example on how to create an NSEvent that simulates pressing return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the [NSEvent Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and more specifically, `-keyEventWithType:location:modifierFlags:timestamp:windowNumber:context:characters:charactersIgnoringModifiers:isARepeat:keyCode:`.

From there, it shouldn't be difficult. Construct all the necessary components, and send the event using `NSApplication`'s `-sendEvent:` method.

Comment: You shouldn't really need an example (it's easy enough to write as it is), but here's one to look at: http://pastie.org/1199967. It assumes a lot of information that you can/should change yourself. It depends on what you are using the key press for, and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am upvoting the answer with an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this Swift-Code for creating a simple Keyboard-Event:

```
    let ThePoint = CGPoint(x:0,y:0)
    let theEventType: NSEventType = NSEventType(rawValue: 10)! // = KeyDown
    let theModifierFlags: NSEventModifierFlags = NSEventModifierFlags(rawValue: 0)
    var event = NSEvent.keyEventWithType(theEventType, location: ThePoint, modifierFlags: theModifierFlags, timestamp: 0.0, windowNumber: 0, context: nil, characters: "\n", charactersIgnoringModifiers: "", isARepeat: false, keyCode: 0)
    NSApplication.sharedApplication().sendEvent(event!)
```